# AWS SDK for PHP won't work in multiple directories

Tags: php, linux, sdk, amazon-web-services, directory

I have AWS SDK for PHP installed into */usr/share/php/*

When I execute sample files from this directory, it works fine.

My web root directory is */var/www/*

When I execute sample files from this directory, they do not work.

Here is a sample file */var/www/test_sdk.php*:

```
<?php

require_once 'sdk.class.php';

$s3 = new AmazonS3();  

$bucket = 'test_bucket' . time();

$response = $s3->create_bucket($bucket, AmazonS3::REGION_US_W1, AmazonS3::ACL_PUBLIC);

if ((int) $response->isOK()) {
echo 'Created Bucket';
}else {
echo (string) $response->body->Message;
}
?>
```

I think the problem is in my 'require_once' statement.  I have tried:

```
"require_once '/usr/share/php/AWSSDKforPHP/sdk.class.php'"
```

It didn't work

Any help is greatly appreciated!!

Answer (score 0):

Is `/usr/share/php/` in your PHP includes path? Have you tried simply installing via [PEAR](http://pear.amazonwebservices.com)?

Comment: Thanks for the quick response!  /usr/share/php/ is already in my PHP includes path.  I needed to change the above statement to require once 'AWSSDKforPHP/sdk.class.php' and it works now!

Answer (score 0):

/usr/share/php/ is already in my PHP includes path.  This was the only change I needed to make to get it working:

```
require_once 'AWSSDKforPHP/skd.class.php'
```